# PHP: word wrap the text inside the PDF?

Tags: php, fpdf

Would you know how to word wrap the text inside the PDF? I am using an array like:

$email_message =" fax: ".clean_string($fax)."\n
";
$email_message .=" address: ".clean_string($address)."\n
"; 
$email_message .=" email: ".clean_string($email)."\n
";

but the break tags show up within the PDF, I would like each one to go on a new line. 
I am using FPDF & Pear's Mime classes to generate the PDF.

Comment: have you tried [`wordwrap`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) function?

Answer (score 2):

with a loop you can go through the

```
$posY = $pdf->GetY();
$nl = 4.5;
$temptext = explode("\n",$email_message );
foreach($temptext as $newline) {
    $pdf->Text(10,$posY+$nl,$newline);
    $nl += 4.5;
}
```